# How can I select a font for a specific market? (e.g. beauty products in Brazil?)

Tags: typography, logo

I am designing a brand for the Brazilian Market. It is focused mainly on beauty products for the mass. So the font I choose needs to be with some personality, not too fancy, not too simple.

How can I narrow down a group of fonts to choose from that will fit my needs?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your original question was _extremely_ localized and heavily subjective, so I edited it slightly to expand the scope.

Answer (score 7):

The *way to approach a problem like this* is through **research and *[moodboarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mood_board)*** - explore popular products in Brasil among the demographics and market your client is targeting, look for clues as to changing trends, explore things (in Brasil or anywhere) that have the kind of personality you want, assemble a big board (physical or digital) of examples of things that have the kind of personality you're looking for, compare it to the competitors, and then use this when your browse fonts.

When you find something that looks plausible, take it to your moodboards and think, 'How does this *fit*?'

[How to create mood boards: 35 expert tips (Creative Bloq)](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/mood-boards-812470)

As you can probably see, this all depends on the exact nature of the brand and client you're working for: so **it's something you need to do yourself**. People who know design trends in Brasil might be able to suggest relevant local styles and trends to be aware of, but they don't know your client.

If a random stranger on the internet could understand your client and their needs as well as you do, your problem isn't fonts: it's a sign that you need a deeper understanding of your client.

Comment: I was thinking about adding an answer, but I'll just chip in to this one by emphasizing that design doesn't happen in a vacuum. If you're in Brazil, go to the local pharmacy and take a picture of the shelf where your product would go. You need to be different than those products, but your product/typeface needs to belong on that shelf.

Comment: I have mixed opinions of moodboard, but they can certainly work in the right situations. They are, essentially, *research* which is the key here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct connection between any particular typeface and a particular market--be it industry or nationality.

There are styles and trends that can be equated to one, however, though they are by no means set-in-stone rules.

You mention Beauty products. A quick google search shows some broad consistencies:

https://www.google.com/search?q=beauty+ad

You find a lot of:

- modern sans (such as Futura)
- high-contrast didones (such as Bodoni)
- flared serifs (such as Optima)

But there's plenty of variations there, and even then, these are just what is common. You can always be the exception.

Bottom line? There are no rules other than the rules of good typography. Beyond that, it's up to you to find a typeface that fits the overall brand message you are trying to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely look at [Google Fonts](http://google.com/fonts). Use the tab bar and select "Word" and change the Preivew Text to Lalina. You can filter over on the right by thickness, slant, and width, as well as select the type of font. I would just do some searching on there. There are tons of script and display fonts that will probably suit your needs. I just quickly ran through and found [some examples](http://www.google.com/fonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect/Collection%3aStalemate%7CSofia%7CKite+One%7CAlex+Brush%7CMrs+Saint+Delafield%7CGreat+Vibes%7CImprima%7CProsto+One). You have a better idea of the brand, but its really easy to find good fonts on there.

Comment: As great as Google Fonts is, it's an incredibly limited set. I wouldn't use that as a basis for research.